# Robot Motion - Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, robotics

Given a 1D world of infinite length (x),
and available moves (y) of, for example [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3],
and a destination (d) (ie 15), write a function that returns
the smallest number of moves (result) needed to reach d.

For example if d = 15, result = 5
since the most optimal move is 3, and it can be done 5 times.

This problem is very similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0ZqKpToTic 
except that negative values are allowed.

I have the code below that only works for positive number. Any ideas to make it work for mixed positive and negative values?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int Robotmotion(vector<int> &moves, int &d) {
        if (d == 0) return 0;
        if (d < 0) {
            d = -d;
            for (auto &move : moves) move *= -1;
        }

        sort(moves.begin(), moves.end());

        vector<int> dp(d + 1, d + 1);

        dp[0] = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < moves.size(); j++) {
                if (moves[j] <= i) {
                    dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i - moves[j]] + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return dp[d] == d + 1 ? -1 : dp[d];
    }
};



int main() {

    Solution s;
    vector<int> moves = {1,2,3};
    int d = 15;
    int min_steps = s.Robotmotion(moves, d);
    cout << "Mim steps:" << endl << min_steps << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something or maybe you've under-complicated your question, but why not `steps = abs(distance) /3 + abs(distance) % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: Hi in the question it is just a simple example. The moves and destination can be any integers. You don't know move and d before hand.

Comment: Is it legal to overshoot and backtrack? As in if you can move 10 and then -1 instead of having to got 3 three times?

Comment: You can overshot. Suppose the move is (-1,2) and d=1, you take two step and you overshoot one step. But you can also take -1 first and 2 then to avoid overshot right?

Comment: The end result is the same, but overshooting and backtracking may simplify the system. You can keep exercising the same logic, then correct by applying the same logic in the other direction. Not so helpful for the human brain, but modern computers are really good at doing the same thing over and over. Probably also worth generating a matrix of the possible distances that can be travelled in the smallest number of moves so you don't have to keep recomputing.

Comment: @alex how about **improving** your _available_ _move_ _array which contains avilable moves and numbers of moves required to do it.  Example - if `y=[1,3,5,-1]` than **improved** `y=[1(1), 2(2), 3(1),4(2),5(1)]` where value in `()` is number of moves needed to do it. Like we can move **4 spaces** by **5 + -1** moves, so cost being 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think dynamic programming can solve the problem. Instead, you should view the number as vertices in a graph and use BFS to solve the problem. You can even use a bidirectional BFS to speed up the process.